# AccessDeniedException while starting pipeline

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS Lambda with AWS CDK to start my `Pipeline`

```
const PipelinesParams = {
        name: "GatsbyPipelineLolly",
    }
    try {
        const pipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline();
        await docClient.put(params).promise();
        pipeline.startPipelineExecution(
            PipelinesParams,
            function (err: any, data: any) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        )
```

and that's the action I authorized

```
const policy = new PolicyStatement();
policy.addActions('s3:*');
policy.addResources('*');
policy.addActions('codepipeline:*');
```

still getting unauthorized error image is also been attached for review

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the policy is attached to the role, with which you are deploying the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created a policy but haven't attached it to the role you are using (from your error message). Please see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html#using-existing-roles and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Policy.html#roles

```
const role = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role', 'arn:aws:iam...')
policy.attachToRole(role)
```