# can a sns.Topic.fromTopicArn be used to run a CodePipeline

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm new to aws and my task is to rebuild the app (trigger the codepipeline) when we receive an sns message.

looking for something similar to the code below but not on a schedule instead using sns but i dont think i can use an sns event:

```
// A pipeline being used as a target for a CloudWatch event rule.
import * as targets from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';
import * as events from '@aws-cdk/aws-events';

// kick off the pipeline every day
const rule = new events.Rule(this, 'Daily', {
  schedule: events.Schedule.rate(Duration.days(1)),
});

declare const pipeline: codepipeline.Pipeline;
rule.addTarget(new targets.CodePipeline(pipeline));
```

these are the code fragments i collected but i dont think i can do what i want to do using a lambda function either.

```
    const consumerTopic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(
        this,
        "myTopicId",
        "arn:aws:sns:*******");

    const fn = new Function(this, 'aFunction', {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      handler: 'snsHandler.handler',
      code: Code.fromAsset(__dirname),
    });

    consumerTopic.addSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(fn))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a pipeline when you receive a sns message like this:

```
    // create sns topic
    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'MyTopic');

    // or subscribe to an existing sns topic
    const consumerTopic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(
        this,
        "myTopicId",
        "arn:aws:sns:***YOUR ARN***");


    const fn = new Function(this, 'aFunction', {
      description: "lambda function to trigger a code pipeline build from a sns message",
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      handler: 'snsHandler.handler',
      code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, '../lambda')),
    });

    consumerTopic.addSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(fn))

    //  create a policy statement
    const policy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution'],
      resources: ['*'],
    });


    //  add the policy to the Function's role
    fn.role?.attachInlinePolicy(
        new iam.Policy(this, 'run-pipeline-policy', {
          statements: [policy],
        }),
    );

    // ***** set a message:
    // aws sns publish \
    // --subject "Just testing " \
    // --message "Hello world " \
    // --topic-arn "***YOUR ARN***"
```

and the lambda function:

```
import { SNSMessage } from 'aws-lambda';
import {AWSError} from "aws-sdk";
import {StartPipelineExecutionOutput} from "aws-sdk/clients/codepipeline";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function(event:SNSMessage) {
    const codePipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline({region: "ap-southeast-2" });
    const params = {
        name: '***NAME OF CODE PIPELINE**', /* required */
        // clientRequestToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
    };

    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        codePipeline.startPipelineExecution(params, function(err:AWSError, data:StartPipelineExecutionOutput) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                reject(err)
            } // an error occurred
            else     {
                console.log(data);
                resolve(data)
            }           // successful response
        });
    })
};
```

one more example here:

[AccessDeniedException while starting pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531600/accessdeniedexception-while-starting-pipeline)